# Generate html-file and scrape it

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape a website with HtmlAgilityPack, but the only time it works is when I copy the html-code and paste it in a local file. And then scrape that file. Why is that? How do I work around this problem?

I get the error: "The indata string had a faulty format", kind of..
Does it have anything to do with the document-encoding?

Note that it does neither work when I StreamWrite the code to a html-document.

Thank you.

Comment: Post your code, please :)

Comment: using WebClient.DownloadString(url) to download it as a string, and then im using HtmlDocument to go through the nodes.

Unedited for pasting: http://codepaste.net/jv2p9w

Comment: Can you `Console.Writeline` your downloaded `string`? Does it look good? Is it empty, null, etc?

Comment: It looks fine, it only works I copy the source-code directly from the target site, and then paste it into my document.

@Mihai

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that System.Net.WebClient is not working as I thought. I used HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb and it works!